# Unable to change user in security context of symlink

Tags: users, selinux

I have created a few symbolic links to replace some broken links in `/etc/pam.d`. The original links have `system_u` as the user. The newly created ones somehow have `unconfined_u` as the user. I am not sure if there is any security implications to this though the target files all have `system_u` as the user.

I tried the following:

```
# restorecon -v thefilename
```

and

```
# chcon -v -u system_u thefilename
```

Both methods do not lead to any change to the user in SELinux security context. Why is that so? Is there any security risk if I don't change the user? And how to make the change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What effect do the user and role labels have on a file in SELinux?](http://serverfault.com/questions/453665/what-effect-do-the-user-and-role-labels-have-on-a-file-in-selinux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SELinux user is ignored in the default `targeted` policy. It is fine to leave them as is, unless you plan to use the `strict` or `mls` policies, or use confined users.

As for changing the context of a symbolic link, you need to use the `-h` option to `chcon` so that it changes the context of the symlink, rather than the file to which it points.

Comment: Thanks for the link to explain what is a targeted policy. Does it explain why SELinux-user could not be changed or is there some other reasons?

Comment: You forgot the `-h` option to `chcon`.