# selinux, file not matching file_contexts.local

Tags: selinux

```
semanage fcontext  -a -t puppet_etc_t "/etc/puppet/environments(/.*)?"
cat  /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local
# This file is auto-generated by libsemanage
# Do not edit directly.

/etc/puppet/environments(/.*)?    system_u:object_r:puppet_etc_t:s0

 touch /etc/puppet/environments/hello1
 ls -Z /etc/puppet/environments/hello1 
 -rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:puppet_etc_t:s0 /etc/puppet/environments/hello1
```

why is this file created as "unconfined_u" not as "system_u" ? 
How can I change it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you created the file while logged in as an unconfined user.

Since in the targeted policy [the user is almost always ignored](https://serverfault.com/a/453852/126632), this really isn't an issue.

If you really want to change it, you can use `chcon` to do that. For instance:

```
# ls -Z /etc/nsswitch.conf.ipabkp
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   /etc/nsswitch.conf.ipabkp
# chcon -u system_u /etc/nsswitch.conf.ipabkp 
# ls -Z /etc/nsswitch.conf.ipabkp
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       /etc/nsswitch.conf.ipabkp
```