# Change selinux context for TLS cacert.pem

Tags: selinux

I need to make **/etc/pki/CA/certs/cacert.pem** have the same context as all the other files in **/etc/pki**:
*system_u:object_r:cert_t:s0*

Tried **restorecon -vR /etc/pki** and **semanage fcontext** but the file remains in the *unconfined_u:object_r:cert_t:s0* context.

Comment: Your context should be fine. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The libvirt wiki says the file needs to be `system_u:object_r:cert_t:s0`

http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/TLSCreateCACert

Comment: Show us the output of `matchpathcon /etc/pki/CA/certs/cacert.pem` and `semanage fcontext -l | grep '^/etc/pki(/'`. Although I agree with Michael that what you have should be ok.

Comment: [The user part is ignored](http://serverfault.com/a/453852/126632) in the SELinux targeted policy, which is what everyone runs by default. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: `[root@kvm ~]# matchpathcon /etc/pki/libvirt/private/kvm_server_privkey.pem
system_u:object_r:cert_t:s0`  
-and-  
`[root@kvm ~]# semanage fcontext -l | grep '^/etc/pki(/'
/etc/pki(/.*)?                                     all files          system_u:object_r:cert_t:s0`

Comment: For the life of me I don't know how these magically got fixed.

Answer (score 2):

### Quick fix

Since your other files are fine, select a specific one for this command:

```
chcon --reference /etc/pki/CA/certs/validcontextcert.pem /etc/pki/CA/certs/cacert.pem
```

### Longer term fix

You can make a context in SELinux for your file so that it is persistent across context restores.

```
semanage fcontext -a -u system_u -r object_r -t cert_t '/etc/pki/CA/certs/cacert.pem'
```

This will make a new context definition that is not yet applied so apply it.

```
restorecon -RvF /etc/pki
```

Comment: `matchpathcon /etc/pki/CA/certs/cacert.pem
/etc/pki/CA/certs/cacert.pem    system_u:object_r:cert_t:s0` The default should be correct.

Comment: @bgstack15

`[djb@kvm ~]$ sudo semanage fcontext -a -u system_u -r object_r -t cert_t '/etc/pki/CA/certs/cacert.pem'
[sudo] password for msh: 
usage: semanage [-h]
                
                {import,export,login,user,port,interface,module,node,fcontext,boolean,permissive,dontaudit}
                ...
semanage: error: unrecognized arguments: -u /etc/pki/CA/certs/cacert.pem`

Comment: This answer seems incorrect (in agreement with mr.zog). **semanage fcontext** accepts no **-u** parameter and **-r** does not change the role, but rather the MLS/MCS security range. Source: **man semanage-fcontext**.